# Vanishing of $\pi_n(X\times Y, X\vee Y)$ for $n\leq p+q+1$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $X,Y$ be (based) CW-complexes (assume $X,Y$ are nice so that there is no problem with $X\times Y$). If $X$ is $p$-connected and $Y$ is $q$-connected, how to show that $(X\times Y, X\vee Y)$ is $(p+q+1)$-connected?

I think I need to use the following result (Theorem 4.23 of Hatcher):
Let $X = A\cup B, C = A\cap B$. If $(A,C)$ is $m$-connected and $(B,C)$ is $n$-connected, then $\pi_i(A,C)\to \pi_i(X,B)$ is an isomorphism for $i<m+n$.

But I failed to decompose $X\times Y$ into two subsets that are useful to solve this problem. I know $\pi_{n+1}(X\times Y, X\vee Y)$ is a direct summand of $\pi_n(X\vee Y)$, but this is not very useful. Maybe I am missing something very obvious.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X$ is $p$-connected, you should choose a CW model for it with no cells in dimensions between 1 and $p$, and similarly for $Y$. Also choose models with a single $0$-cell (that's probably guaranteed already unless $p=0$ or $q=0$). The first interesting cells $e \times e'$ in $X \times Y$ (by which I mean the first cells that are not in $X \vee Y$) will have dimension at least $p+q+2$, since $\dim e \geq p+1$ and $\dim e' \geq q+1$.